# How to access looped div tag in Typescript file

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

```
<div  class="mx-0 p-2 row"  style="box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);">
    <div #myDiv (click)="navToOrder(value.agId,value.invoiceId,value.tableNo,value.currStageName)" [style.background-color]="value.currStageColor"

        class="table1 m-3"  *ngFor="let value of dashBoardTableList ;let i=index"     
        tooltip={{value.currStageName}} placement="top">
        <span class="homeTopLabel ">{{value.noOfCovers}}</span>
        <span class="leftGlass">
            <i *ngIf="value.currStageName!='Empty'" class="fa fa-glass "></i>
            <i *ngIf="value.currStageName=='Empty'" class=" fa fa-glass fa-flip-vertical"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="fa-stack middlePlate">
            <i class="fa fa-genderless fa-stack-2x" style="font-size:35px;"></i><i class="fa fa-spoon fa-stack-1x"
                style="font-size: 15px;top: 5px;left: -1.5px;"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="rightGlass">
            <i *ngIf="value.currStageName!='Empty'" class="fa fa-glass "></i>
            <i *ngIf="value.currStageName=='Empty'" class=" fa fa-glass fa-flip-vertical"></i>
        </span>

        <span class="homeBlabel">{{value.tableNo}}</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here I want to get a specific index of div tag unfortunately Tabindex is not working fine.Is there any other way ?

Comment: where do you want to get it? you have created a variable i in ngFor. doesn't that provide the index to you?

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for the reply,Yes It will provide,but I need to apply styles through typescript and i want in ts file.how to get the particular index.For eg,I have view child and how to point the particular index of div tag.I hope you get it

Comment: use viewchildren instead of viewchild

Comment: Please don't use ViewChildren for this if you can avoid it (which you mostly can). It's pretty serious code smell. I've offered a more "Angular" solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Applying styles using @ViewChild is generally an Angular anti-pattern.

It sounds like what you really want here is a Directive that takes the index of the element as an argument, something like:

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myStyleDirective]'
})
export class MyStyleDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() itemIndex!: number;
  
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const styleValue = this.itemIndex % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'styleToChange', styleValue);
  }
}
```

You then place the directive on your element:

```html
<div *ngFor="let value of dashBoardTableList ;let i=index"
     myStyleDirective
     [itemIndex]="i"
     (click)="navToOrder(value.agId,value.invoiceId,value.tableNo,value.currStageName)"
     [style.background-color]="value.currStageColor"
     class="table1 m-3"
     tooltip={{value.currStageName}}
     placement="top">
```

You could also use `[ngStyle]` or `[ngClass]` and use a method in your TypeScript which returns the appropriate style for a given index. There can be performance issues with that, though, as the method gets called for every change detection cycle.

Comment: Thanks For your Reply,As u mentioned above i created directive.ts and added your code,Unfortunately its not working.Even log also not printing in console which is in directive.ts

Comment: Did you declare the directive in a module and make sure it's available to your feature module? Also, Merna's correction is quite right, I'll edit my answer to take it into account.

Comment: Very Thankyou,Now its working...

Comment: Could I ask that you mark the answer as accepted to make it easier to find for other people with the same issue?

Comment: @VigneshVenkatesan It's considered polite to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Iam Very sorry.I am in need of 10 reputations points to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: OK no worries Vignesh :)

Answer (score 1):

I've voted for the answer of @Will Alexander, but for code, there are minor issues I'll fix it here.
for the selector name, fix it to be `[myStyleDirective]` instead of `'myStyleDirective'`
And for `setStyle` method make sure that you are passing the correct parameters, especially for the name of the style and the value for the style
Here is a working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-afterviewinit-srodk6?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.directive.ts)

Comment: Thanks for catching that Merna, I've edited my answer for the selector.

Comment: You're welcome Will :)